# How to create audio player elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a audio player in my codes and want to append source to the audio player.
I am not using html5 so it's a bit different.

I have

```
var audioPlayer=document.createElement('audio');
      audioPlayer.id='audioPlayer';
      audioPlayer.className='audioPlayer'


 var audioSource=document.createElement('source');
 audioSource.src='song.mp3'

 $(this).closest('div').append(audioPlayer);
 audioPlayer.innerHTML=audioSource; //won't do it......
```

I want the html like this

```
<audio id='audioPlayer' class='audioPlayer>
<source src='song.mp3'></source>
</audio>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you forget to append your audiosource to audioplayer?  Audiosource is a child of audioplayer in your example.

```
var audioPlayer=document.createElement('audio');
audioPlayer.id='audioPlayer';
audioPlayer.className='audioPlayer'
var audioSource=document.createElement('source');
audioSource.src='song.mp3'
audioPlayer.appendChild(audioSource);

$(this).closest('div').append(audioPlayer);
//audioPlayer.innerHTML=audioSource;
```

try it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecco88/Q5RT5/)